# Android Studio 2.1

Tags: android, sdk, installation

Good Day,

I had to format my drive due to some errors, but before I did, I have copied all the zip files form the temp directory that contained the android sdk's now instead of downloading all of them again how do I install the SDK's and how do i determine where which one goes?

I have tried to set up a webserver on my localhost with all the zip files and pointed android studio to use that as a update location but for some reason it is not reading the data from there.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK you need to provide the location of Android base SDK folder and it shall automatically pick up Platforms folders under which all your Android version should be listed. You do not need to reinstall whole stuff.

Also make sure ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME is properly set inside Environment variables and PATH